cannot coerce class "umap" to a data.frame in R
despite I found many posts dealing with this error such as this one, this one, this one and also this one I am pretty much new to visualization using umap . Those posts were useful in many other ways, but I am not able to solve the error: cannot coerce class ‘"umap"’ to a data.frame.
Can anyone with some experience using umap try to point to a solution? Thank you so much.
I created a small verifiable example:
library(readxl)
library(stats)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(umap)

df <- read_xlsx("/path/to/excel_file/umap/test.xlsx", sheet = 2)

# The test.xlsx file mentioned has the following format
#
#  Samples  | Condition
#  ABC001   |   Toxic
#  ABC002   |   Toxic
#  ABC003   |   NonToxic
#  ABC004   |   NonToxic
#  ABC005   |   NonToxic
#

file_names <- df$Samples[df$Condition == "Toxic" | df$Condition == "NonToxic"]
file_suffixes <- file_names[grepl("ABC", file_names)]

file_paths <- paste("/path/to/all/txt/TOXICOLOGY/", file_suffixes, ".txt", sep="")
file_paths <- head(file_paths, 13) # I have a total of 13 files

# Each file in the folder TOXICOLOGY above has the folloing format:
#
# Gene            Node   Entropy
# ENSG00000163762 1      NA
# ENSG00000163762 2      0.9991
# ENSG00000163762 8      0.0
# ENSG00000163999 9      0.5763
# ENSG00000049999 1      NA
# ENSG00000045555 4      0.0
# ENSG00000045555 5      0.0
# ENSG00000045555 6      NA
# ENSG00000088239 9      0.0
# ENSG00000088239 10     NA
# ENSG00000188811 1      NA
# ENSG00000188811 2      NA
#


# Function to read and process each file
process_file <- function(file_path) {
  data <- read.table(file_path, sep="", header=TRUE)
  data <- na.omit(data)
  data <- data.frame(Gene_Node = paste(data$Gene, data$Node, sep = "_"), data)
  data <- data[, -c(2,3)]
  return(data)
}

diseased <- lapply(file_paths, process_file)
diseased_dt <- lapply(diseased, as.data.table)

# Get keys from the first data table
common_keys <- diseased_dt[[1]][, unique(Gene_Node)]

# Intersect keys with all other data tables
for (dt in diseased_dt[-1]) {
  common_keys <- intersect(common_keys, dt[, unique(Gene_Node)])
  if (length(common_keys) == 0) break
}

# Filter data tables to only include common keys
filtered_dt_list <- lapply(diseased_dt, function(dt) dt[Gene_Node %in% common_keys, ])

unique_dt_list <- lapply(filtered_dt_list, function(dt) {
  dt[, .(Entropy = mean(Entropy, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Gene_Node]
})

# Rename the second column in each data table to a unique name if necessary
unique_dt_list <- lapply(seq_along(unique_dt_list), function(i, unique_dt_list) {
  setnames(unique_dt_list[[i]], old = names(unique_dt_list[[i]])[2], new = paste("ABC", sub(".*/ABC([0-9]+).txt", "\\1", file_paths[[i]]), sep=""))
  unique_dt_list[[i]]
}, unique_dt_list) 

# Then merge
result_dt <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Gene_Node", all = FALSE), unique_dt_list)
diseased_merged <- result_dt

# Transpose the dataframe for PCA
df_t <- as.data.frame(t(diseased_merged))
colnames(df_t) <- as.character(unlist(df_t[1, ]))
df_t <- df_t[-1, ]
df_t[] <- lapply(df_t, function(x) if(is.character(x)) as.numeric(x) else x)


# Run UMAP
umap_data <- as.data.frame(df_t)
umap_results <- umap(df_t, n_neighbors = 13, min_dist = 0.1, n_components = 3, metric = "euclidean")


# Extract the condition labels for each sample (assuming the order is maintained)
condition_labels <- df %>%
  filter(Samples %in% file_suffixes) %>%
  pull(Condition)

# Convert the matrix to a dataframe
umap_data <- as.data.frame(umap_results)   <-- ERROR HERE cannot coerce class ‘"umap"’ to a data.frame
colnames(umap_data) <- c("UMAP1", "UMAP2", "UMAP3")
umap_data$Condition <- condition_labels  # Assuming you have condition labels prepared

# Plot using plotly
# Plotting results

Thank you so much for shedding some light on this problem.

This isn't a useful example because you are reading files from your local machine which we do not have so we can not run and test the code. What exactly do you want the resulting data.frame to look like? What are the columns and rows you are expecting?
